# Deploy web.config file using MSDeploy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdeploy

Here is my requirement:

I want to be able to deploy my project in such a way that my web.config is not overwritten and stays intact. For all the changes that have been made to web.config during development are copied to a file called new_web.config and that is loaded to the server during the deployment. 
So that server now has total of two files web.config(The original one before deployment) and new_web.config(the new one).

To achieve that I am doing a Copy from web.config to new_web.config on

and had set BuildAction for web.config= None.

Thats would work fine if the deployment process is copying all the files over from source to destination.

But it is not working in my case because it is deleting all the files in destination folder and then copying all the files from the source.

Can anyone suggest any work around this?

Comment: Are you aware of web.config transforms? If your web.config on the server needs to be preserved because it has environment-specific settings, then the transforms will solve that problem for you.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of XSLT transformations. I definitely see the harm in not preserving web.config. Thanks for pointing out. Just wondering if MSBuild is capable of what I want with copying file contents in new file and preserving the old file(as if it is not web.config and some another txt file).

Comment: No, not XSLT transforms. [Web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx).

Comment: Config transforms do seem like a good approach here. FYI in VS2012 you now can create publish profile specific transforms. See Hanselman's post at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures3PublishingImprovementsChainedConfigTransformsAndDeployingASPNETAppsFromTheCommandLine.aspx.

Comment: Actually, I am using web.config transforms but by mistake I referred to it as XSLT transforms my bad....